# Pick Url Option in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I am using Visual Studio 2013 but earlier I was using Visual Studio 2010. In Asp.net Visual Studio 2010, for script tags when we type **src =** automatically the **Pick Url** option will pop up i.e.  `<script type="text/javascript" src=`, so as to select the appropriate javascript file from the solution.

But in Visual Studio 2013 for script tags when we type **src =** the  **Pick Url** option is not popping up, don't know why. Please refer the screen shot taken from VS 2010 when we type script tag src,   [PleaseClickHereToVIewScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDt1c.jpg). This option is not popping up in VS 2013.

Please advise if there is any other option in Visual Studio 2013  that will enable this feature.

Please also advise how to enable the **Pick Url** option in Razor MVC.

thanks,
Balaji

Answer (score 1):

In a MVC application, I can add the script tag to a cshtml file and after typing a space I get a dropdown with possible attributes. If I type src and press TAB, I can select a file (or go up a folder and browse to a file).

[Edit]

I just had a similar behavior.

It took a few minutes, to realize that if you just start typing the context menu appears.
Although you have to know the name of the next folder or file to get it in the next list.
But you can remove the last slash to get all the items in the context menu.

[image]

Not 100% perfect, but I hope it helps.

Comment: This option is not popping up in VS 2013, please refer the screen shot taken from VS 2010 when we type script tag src,   [PleaseClickHereToVIewScreenShot](http://i.imgur.com/3QdwAbm.jpg)  hope it clarifies..

Comment: Edited the post after Balaji commented about it.

Answer (score 1):

The other alternative would be to drag and drop files(.css and .js) from solution explorer directly to the .cshtml file. By this way we can get the path of the file